# Pattern for Java ConcurrentHashMap of Sets

Tags: java, concurrent-programming, concurrenthashmap

A data structure that I use commonly in multi-threaded applications is a ConcurrentHashMap where I want to save a group of items that all share the same key. The problem occurs when installing the first item for a particular key value.

The pattern that I have been using is:

```
final ConcurrentMap<KEYTYPE, Set<VALUETYPE>> hashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<KEYTYPE, Set<VALUETYPE>>();
// ...
Set<VALUETYPE> newSet = new HashSet<VALUETYPE>();
final Set<VALUETYPE> set = hashMap.putIfAbsent(key, newSet)
if (set != null) {
  newSet = set;
}
synchronized (newSet) {
  if (!newSet.contains(value)) {
    newSet.add(value);
  }
}
```

Is there a better pattern for doing this operation? Is this even thread-safe? Is there a better class to use for the inner `Set` than `java.util.HashSet`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly recommend using the [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) libraries for this, specifically an implementation of [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). The [HashMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html) would be your best bet, though if you need concurrent update opterations you would need to wrap it in a delegate using [Multimaps.synchronizedSetMultimap()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#synchronizedSetMultimap%28com.google.common.collect.SetMultimap%29).

Another option is to use a `ComputingMap` (also from Guava), which is a map that, if the Value returned from a call to `get(Key)` does not exist, it is instantiated there and then. `ComputingMap`s are created using [MapMaker](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html).

The code from your question would be roughly:

```
ConcurrentMap<KEYTYPE, Set<VALUETYPE>> hashMap = new MapMaker()
                 .makeComputingMap(
        new Function<KEYTYPE, VALUETYPE>() {
         public Graph apply(KEYTYPE key) {
           return new HashSet<VALUETYPE>();
         }
       });
```

The `Function` would only be called when a call to `get()` for a specific key would otherwise return null. This means that you can then do this:

```
hashMap.get(key).put(value);
```

safely knowing that the `HashSet<VALUETYPE>` is created if it doesn't already exist.

`MapMaker` is also relevant because of the control it gives you over the tuning of the returned Map, letting you specify, for example, the concurrency level using the method `concurrencyLevel()`. You may find that useful:

> Guides the allowed concurrency among update operations. Used as a hint for internal sizing. The table is internally partitioned to try to permit the indicated number of concurrent updates without contention. Because assignment of entries to these partitions is not necessarily uniform, the actual concurrency observed may vary.

Comment: What kind of thread-safe guarantees are made by the Guava collections? From the JavaDocs for `HashMultimap`: "This class is not threadsafe when any concurrent operations update the multimap. Concurrent read operations will work correctly. To allow concurrent update operations, wrap your multimap with a call to Multimaps.synchronizedSetMultimap(com.google.common.collect.SetMultimap)." Within the `java.util.*` collections, the `concurrent` package was added because the performance of `Collections.synchronizedMap()` is very poor.

Comment: That is probably something you will need to evaluate yourself. Another option is to use a Computing Map - I will update my answer with an example of that too.

Comment: Guava does not provide a fully concurrent `Multimap`, largely because it's _extremely_ difficult to do.

Comment: That said, I _think_ you're doing it the way I would.

Comment: @LouisWasserman when you say "you're", are you referring to the OP or to me? :)

Comment: Sorry.  The OP is doing things roughly the way I would, if I were trying to correctly implement a more concurrent multimap -- but `synchronizedSetMultimap` is _known_ to work, whereas I'm not nearly as confident as I ought to be that the OP's technique works.  Achieve a correct solution first, and only then optimize things like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think using [`java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) and [`java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) could help you resolve the concurrency concerns.