# Functional equivalent to the concurrent multimap

Tags: scala, clojure, functional-programming

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822314/pattern-for-java-concurrenthashmap-of-sets), I asked about concurrent multimaps for Java.

Is there some functional programming (immutable) pattern that can be used instead in a Scala or Clojure program? I image that the Scala solution will probably involve actors and the clojure one an `atom`, `ref` or `agent`, but there may be a better way. Since both languages allow "falling back" to Java interop and just using a Java solution, I can use whatever answer I get to my first question, but that will not adhere to the functional programming paradigm. How do Haskell programmers solve this?

Comment: It is a common misconception that Haskell does not allow mutation. It does. The catch is that all mutation must be duly noted in the types; therefore the typical way to compose mutation operations together is with the monad interface. Haskellers can "fall back" to mutability in much the same way as Scala and Clojure, except in Haskell you can't cheat and make it look like a function is pure when it is not. However, if you can completely encapsulate the mutation in your function, then it can still expose a pure interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Standard Clojure maps and sets are immutable (and persistent)[1], so they work just as well in concurrent programs.  You may want to store them in a ref/agent/var/atom depending on your requirements, and you can just update the ref/agent/var/atom as ever.

You can have a more mutable map, if the values are actually refs, like this:

```
{:a (ref #{1 2 3})
 :b (ref #{4 5 6})}
```

In this case, you'll be able to actually add values to already existing key (in transaction of course).  Addition and removal of keys will still return new maps, which would share the same refs as the original maps, and so changes to one of them will be visible to the others:

```
user=> (def mmap {:a (ref #{1 2 3}) :b (ref #{4 5 6})})
#'user/mmap
user=> mmap
{:a #<Ref@be0446: #{1 2 3}>, :b #<Ref@10aa282: #{4 5 6}>}
user=> (def mmap2 (assoc mmap :c (ref #{7 8 9})))
#'user/mmap2
user=> mmap2
{:c #<Ref@405f6: #{7 8 9}>, :a #<Ref@be0446: #{1 2 3}>, :b #<Ref@10aa282: #{4 5 6}>}
user=> mmap
{:a #<Ref@be0446: #{1 2 3}>, :b #<Ref@10aa282: #{4 5 6}>}
user=> (dosync (alter (:a mmap2) conj 0))
#{0 1 2 3}
user=> mmap
{:a #<Ref@be0446: #{0 1 2 3}>, :b #<Ref@10aa282: #{4 5 6}>}
user=> mmap2
{:c #<Ref@405f6: #{7 8 9}>, :a #<Ref@be0446: #{0 1 2 3}>, :b #<Ref@10aa282: #{4 5 6}>}
```

[1] That is, adding/removing/modifying keys, and values actually return a new map, without changing the original.

Answer (score 3):

A functional data structure is an immutable data structure. Immutable data structures do not have problems with concurrency because they cannot be modified.

Comment: Is an Actor (or actor-like class) the only thread-safe way to manage this data structure.

Comment: @Ralph not at all. Actors are useful, but they're not a catch-all for any concurrency issue. As Daniel saya, you don't need any sort of management of an immutable structure. The question then becomes whether you need mutability, and if so in what way. More detail would help here.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation in Scala in Akka library

https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.3.0/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/util/Index.scala